# time - ( minus ) time = time ( seconds ) in php

Tags: php

lets say i have two input, date 1 and date2 somehow i need the difference in seconds

```
Thu, 26 May 2011 11:40:00 +0000 
Thu, 26 May 2011 11:39:40 +0000 
===============================
                     120 minutes x 60 + 20 seconds
```

or

```
Thu, 26 May 2011 11:40:00 +0000
Thu, 25 May 2011 11:39:40 +0000
===============================
                     120 minutes + 24 hours ( one day ) / 60x24 = 1440 minutes
                     = 1560 minutes x 60 + 20 seconds
```

so on..

**how can we do something like above using php?**

*edit forgot about the secs.

Thanks for looking in!.

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150991/get-time-difference

Comment: @pavium sorry i didn't see that earlier, its on different format anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `DateTime` class. Note that `diff()` is a >= PHP 5.3 method. If you have an older version, you can always use `strtotime()`.

```
$dateStart = new DateTime('Thu, 26 May 2011 11:40:00 +0000');

$dateFinish = new DateTime('Thu, 25 May 2011 11:39:40 +0000');

echo $dateStart->diff($dateFinish)->s; // 20
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rB5JLm).

Answer (score 2):

```
$diff = strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date2);
```