# Get time difference

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get time difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150991/get-time-difference)

Hi, i need to get time difference between two time in php.

```
$starttime=time();
$endtime=time();
```

how to get hour minute and second in php

thanks

Comment: Fyi, in case it's for profiling: use `microtime(true)` instead of `time()`

Answer (score 3):

```
echo ($endtime-$starttime);
```

Will get you the number of seconds.

If you need to know the hours you can do something like:

```
$seconds = ($endtime-$starttime);
echo floor($seconds/3600).' hours';
```

Comment: `$starttime = 10000; $endtime = 11801;` => `1801 seconds = 1 hours`. You must use `floor()`.

Comment: @king: +1 for the correction....

Answer (score 2):

```
$starttime=time();
$endtime=time();

$diff = $endtime - $starttime;
$hours = floor($diff / 3600);
$minutes = floor (($diff % 3600) / 60);
$seconds = $diff % 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [date_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) for this....

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at strftime

```
$difference = $endtime-$starttime;
echo strftime('%H:%M:%S',$difference);
```

Comment: Manual page here: http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php 
Be warned, though, that this causes problems with timezones, as essentially you are taking the hours, minutes and seconds of a timestamp of seconds after the UNIX epoch. For instance, using a timestamp (the difference in this case) of `1` when the timezone is on BST gives the result `01:00:01`, which is obviously wrong. Setting `date.timezone` to `America/Denver` (as an example) now gives `17:00:01` for the timestamp of `1`.